# How to replace NA in columns with its values in other rows based on when it was recorded and reduce the size of the dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a huge pandas data frame containing data about hospital encounters. This data frame has the following columns: hospital encounter id (`hadm_id`), a `datetime` object indicating the time a variable was charted (`ce_charttime`) and the values of the recorded variables. There are many variables, but for simplicity, I am currently working with only 2 variables heart rate (`hr`) and respiratory rate (`resp`). Here is the head of the data frame:

```
    hadm_id ce_charttime    hr  resp
0   100020  2142-11-30 23:06:00 62.0    NaN
1   100020  2142-11-30 23:06:00 NaN 13.0
2   100021  2109-08-21 20:00:00 134.0   NaN
3   100021  2109-08-21 19:30:00 133.0   NaN
4   100021  2109-08-21 20:00:00 NaN 18.0
```

If you notice, the encounter with `hadm_id=100020`, has two rows. However, both the rows have the same `ce_charttime` with value `2142-11-30 23:06:00`, which means it should really be one row, with one `ce_charttime` having a value for both `hr` and `resp`: `ce_charttime=2142-11-30 23:06:00, hr=62.0, resp=NaN`.

Similarly, for the encounter with `hadm_id=100021`, there are 3 rows, however, there really needs to be only 2 rows. After sorting by time, the first row would have the values `ce_charttime=19:30:00, hr=133.0, resp=NaN` and the second row would have the values `ce_charttime=2109-08-21 20:00:00, hr=134.0, resp=18.0`.

Essentially, I need the data frame to look like this:

```
    hadm_id ce_charttime    hr  resp
0   100020  2142-11-30 23:06:00 62.0    13.0
1   100021  2109-08-21 19:30:00 133.0   NaN
2   100021  2109-08-21 20:00:00 134.0   18.0
```

This is just a sample of the dataframe, this dataframe has more than 30 variables, with more than 8000 unique encounters with a lot of rows with this kind of redundant information. Is there way to filter this redundant information?

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Your expected data is different than your description at row 2.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've corrected it.

Comment: `df.groupby(['hadm_id', 'ce_charttime']).agg('first')`, though you might want to consider what happens if there's a collision between rows where the non-missing data doesn't match.

Comment: @ALollz, that seems to work, however, will the values of the variables be sorted by time for each encounter (each `hadm_id`).  Also, could you please answer the question so that I can mark it as an accepted answer?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if that was the logic you needed, hence the comment. `groupby` will by default sort the output so it will be sorted by `['hadm_id', 'ce_charttime']` It aggregates rows with the same `['hadm_id', 'ce_charttime']` regardless of where they occur in the original DataFrame so you don't need to worry before. However, are there cases where the same `['hadm_id', 'ce_charttime']` could have different non-missing values for some of the fields? `first` (or grouping at all) may not be appropriate in this case

Comment: I understand the question of  @aLollz. But in that case in what way would the rows be arranged? Necessarily an example that reflects all cases

Comment: @ALollz, I believe that is possible. For example, `hr` and `resp`, are routinely taken and also taken together. However, there are certain lab tests that maybe taken less frequently at different times that might have `NaN` values for other variables. In this case, I would want to keep the `NaN` values for the other variables.

Comment: I think your question is too extensive. Or that it should provide a broader data framework. And modify the expected data frame. @shaun

Comment: I also consider that for my solution to fail, samples should be taken in a period of time less than one second. @shaun

Comment: I'm not sure whether the title of this question reflects the actual problem that I am having. Maybe someone can suggest an alternate title so that others might find it easily if they have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GroupBy.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with `min_count=1` to keep `NaN` value:

```
df.groupby(['hadm_id','ce_charttime']).sum(min_count = 1).reset_index()
```

This works if there is no more than one rows (hr,resp) with different values per group

Output:

```
   hadm_id         ce_charttime     hr  resp
0   100020  2142 11-30-23:06:00   62.0  13.0
1   100021  2109 08-21-19:30:00  133.0   NaN
2   100021  2109 08-21-20:00:00  134.0  18.0
```

Comment: I do not. I checked it by adding one of the less frequently taken test for magnesium and I see `NaN`s where its supposed to be `NaN`s and I see values where there are supposed to be values. Thank you for your help!